# Creating hidden arguments with Python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to add an Argument to an python [`argparse.ArgumentParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) without it showing up in the usage or help (`script.py --help`)?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Yes, you can set the `help` option to `add_argument` to `argparse.SUPPRESS`. Here's an example from the [argparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#help):

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='frobble')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: frobble [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: Then it just shows up as `test                ==SUPPRESS==`. At least when used with `add_parser`.

Comment: @ThomasAhle you can, at least partially, [hide subparsers added with `.add_parser()` by omitting the help argument](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/67037#issuecomment-1093669037).

Answer (score 2):

I do it by adding an option to enable the hidden ones, and grab that by looking at `sysv.args`.

If you do this, you have to include the special arg you pick out of `sys.argv` directly in the parse list if you Assume the option is `-s` to enable hidden options.

```
parser.add_argument('-a', '-axis',
                    dest="axis", action="store_true", default=False,
                    help="Rotate the earth")
if "-s" in sys.argv or "-secret" in sys.argv:
    parser.add_argument('-s', '-secret',
                        dest="secret", action="store_true", default=False,
                        help="Enable secret options")
    parser.add_argument('-d', '-drill',
                        dest="drill", action="store_true", default=False,
                        help="drill baby, drill")
```

Comment: This won't work with nested commands, as you don't know where in the hierarchy the `-s` appears in