# Is there a way to make a 'hidden' help menu with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm working on a script for simple spectral data analysis on very big data files. I have a few 'dangerous' but useful argparse positional arguments that I'd like to keep hidden from the `-h` or `--help` menu. I want these to show only when called by an 'hidden' help command, something like `--secrethelp` or whatever. Any idea or hint on how to do this?

Comment: Sounds similar to the question in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114589/creating-hidden-arguments-with-python-argparse

Comment: see command line arguments [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: @prashantrana There's nothing about hidden options there.

Comment: After hiding the options as explained in that question, you can simply add your own `--secrethelp` option that displays a full help, not using the built-in help feature.

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot, this is definitely a solution! i did find the linked question but didn't think about just creating a new option displaying the full help :). Any idea on how to do this in a more 'elegant' way though?

Comment: Maybe you can do something with the customizable help formatter, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hidden positionals sound dangerous.  You'd have to make them `nargs='?'`(or '*').  And having more than one such positional gives more problems.  I think hidden optionals make more sense.

Comment: As for the '--secrethelp', I think that would required a lot of your own code, possibly accessing 'private' attributes.  There's nothing in `argparse` to override the `help=SUPPRESS`.  Either you have to process the `args.secrethelp` attribute after parsing, or make a custom `Action` class.